# Should an access token reflect the current user roles?

Tags: oauth2

A user with role "A" requests an access token at time *t*, which expires in 12 hours; after 6 hours, role "B" is granted to the user in addition to role "A".

Should the token grant the user role "B", even if the role wasn't granted at the time the token was requested?

**UPDATE** Like Mike Scott noticed in his answer, change on user roles should take effect immediately. I'd like to make my question more specific: when user roles change, should active tokens reflect the change granting the updated roles of should them be invalidate/revoked?

In other words: should the authorities granted by a token be immutable?

Answer (score 2):

There is not necessarily a right answer to the question. It is really easy to say "of course they should" and somewhat harder to make it happen.

Given that you set a token with claims rather than just an identifier there is an assumption that you do not want to contact the authorization server every time the token is received. This means you have to respect the validity / expiry of the token.

If you don't mind contacting the authorization server with every request then you don't need to set the claims in the token, you can get them from the server every time and they will always be up to date.

OAuth is usually used between multiple parties and you might control between 1 and all of them. How many you control may affect what you can and can't do. Token revocation is not possible without an additional request to the auth server

Answer (score 1):

Ask the question the other way around, and the answer is obvious. If the user has role B *revoked* while their token is active, the access must be revoked immediately. So you might as well have all access changes take effect immediately.

Comment: Right, but should the token be invalidated or have the same token reflect the change of user grants?

Comment: @GiovanniLovato You should probably keep the same token but change its access privileges. Making users log in again is a security risk in itself, because it encourages them to work around the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

A token is for authentication, not for authorization. A token should contain no information other than what is needed to verify authenticity. A token in itself does nothing, it is usually paired with an account, role, or resource. So:

Token T for user A with role R must specifically either grant authenticity to the bearer for acting as user A, or as user A in combination with role R.

In the case of your scenario:

- if the token T is valid for user A, the assigned roles at the time of the use of token T will be available to the bearer, regardless of the state at the time at which the token was issued
- if the token T is valid for user A in combination with role R, at the time the token is used, authentication will only be successful if user A still has role R assigned

You could enhance authorization speed by revoking all tokens on user mutation events if desirable.

For standalone or offline tokens this doesn’t work, but then again, tokens wouldn’t be effective in that case anyway as they cannot be revoked.